# Reducing space between background and screen sides

Tags: html, css

There is some background div for font:

```
#reset_font{

    margin-top: -10px;
    padding-right: -10px;
    padding-left: -10px;
    height: 800px;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

And for top minus margin works, there is no space between font and window's top. But on the right there is thin line white line( without font) between window on right side and font.
If I set width to 101%, there is no space, but I don't like the idea.

[image]

Comment: What about the rest of your CSS? It would help to see some context - and perhaps set up a fiddle?

Comment: At present it is only one element on page

Comment: Negative padding doesn't work.

Comment: Why someone downvotes without any comment? It is specific question, with code. And it is really stupid to create js fiddle with only one element on page

Comment: I disagree - a fiddle helps other people to help you - it saves them from setting up your fiddle for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space that you see is for `body` and in some browser, for `html`. Just set the `margin` and `padding` to `0` for this two elements:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

- [Here is FIDDLE Demo without removing the gap.](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/JNKQz/)
- [Here is FIDDLE Demo by removing the gap.](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/JNKQz/1/)

Comment: Yeath, that is what I needed

Answer (score 3):

It's quite messy to work with negative margins, as those margins might be browser specific.
What works when getting everything to the sides is something like this:

```
 * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}
```

Put that at the top of your css and you should be good.

Comment: Edited post, this is how it looks on page with your code or without -margin, no elements on page anymore